# Vertical and Horizontal centering using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple login form styled using `Bootstrap 3.3.7`and a wrapper class div. Form looks like it is vertically and horizontally centered, but text boxes overlap for labels when viewed in full browser screen.

How can I make it such that default bootstrap behavior is applied for forms elements?

### HTML

```
<div class="container body-content">
<div class="infobox">
<div class="row">
  <section id="loginForm">
    <form action="" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Email">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Password">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input class="form-control" name="Password" type="password" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
          <div class="checkbox">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </section>
</div>
```

### CSS (.infobox)

```
.infobox {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nneeu1bp/)
[image]

Comment: Both centering and the overlapping are easily solved with CSS Flexbox

Comment: Just change column widths to 3 and 9 instead of 2 and 10.

Comment: Is there a way I can maintain the grids and just manipulate `.infobox` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/arajajyothibabu/nneeu1bp/2/) updated fiddle. Don't keep label as bootstrap columns.

```
    <div class="col-md-10">
                <label for="Email">Email</label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
</div>
```